# Three js STL loading

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am trying to load an **stl** file by just modifying the url of the function `load` of the `loader` in this example : http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html

But I don't know why, it loads and after a certain time the rotation of the scene begins but I can't visualize anything... I tried to put the mesh informations in the console and the mesh does exist, has a geometry, etc.

The STL in itself is quite big (28.2 MB) and comes from CATIA V5.

And loading it in this free online viewer using three.js works : http://www.viewstl.com/

But it doesn't use the `STLLoader.js` the example uses.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?  Specifically, is there anything about Same-Origin, Cross-Origin, etc?

See: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Yes I've checked the developer console, it is written the revision "THREE.WebGLRenderer 72" and that is all.

I don't think it's about local/external policy, I run a local Apache and loading STL coming from Grabcad for example does work, but not the one file I want with STLLoader.js.

The STL file is exported from CATIA (CAD Software).

Comment: If you're receiving no other errors you can try to debug by iterating items in the scene using scene.children.

It may also be possible that your mesh is very large and the camera is inside of it or too close/too far for the set draw distances.  A simple way to test might be to set the material to draw both sides (ie: set material.side = THREE.DoubleSide).

Comment: It is present in scene.children (a THREE.Mesh containing 106 230 faces) and when putting the mesh material side to THREE.DoubleSide, it is still the same, I can see nothing...

Comment: There's a light source?  You can try adding OrbitControls to your project and pan/Zoom around.  STLs can be particularly weird about size and the objects origin - ie you think the model is at 0,0,0 but for some reason every vertex is Z + 100 and the model is waaay up in the air.

Comment: Oh ! I can finally see it...
It was my far plane which wasn't far enough actually...
My model is not at all on position 0 0 0 but indeed very far away

Answer (score 1):

i did that :

```js
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load( 'MY-STL.stl', function ( geometry ) {
     var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                      ambient: 0xff5533, 
                      color: 0xff5533, 
                      specular: 0x111111,
                      shininess: 200 } 
                                                              
                   );
     var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
     
     scene.add( mesh );
    } );
```

so you need to define the material and also need to use